# how to get the value and append using angular?

Tags: angularjs

I did autocomplete in textbox but when i select from the autocomplete is not appending down, but its coming what i type in the textbox,

i tried these much i dont know where i doing mistake
please check this out :http://plnkr.co/edit/NPvT642ZDWu0vsXvnKla?p=preview

i am doing with help of this code:http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/aLDJJ/

**SCRIPT**

```
    $scope.complete=function(){
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: $scope.availableTags
    });
    } 
    $scope.contacts = ["dimond", "hello"];

    $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
    $scope.newcontact = "";
    }
  });
```

I need the text which i select in autocomplete to be append down in ul li, but its not coming please check this out, I tried as much i can, so some one help me out.
thanks

Comment: it's never a good idea to mix angular and jquery in a single function like you have here.

Comment: if its in 2 functions, will it ll be right?

Comment: angular manipulates **data**, jquery manipulates **DOM**.  you can't take the DOM elements and treat them as data like this.  The best recommendation would be to use something like angular Typeahead from angular-ui which does what you want natively.  If, however, you MUST use jquery, you'll have to write a custom jquery function and use it from inside an Angular Directive.

Comment: basically, Angular will never see that jquery has changed the value of the textbox, because it cannot two way bind with non-angular libraries.

Comment: jeez dont mix angular and jquery. if you want a typeahead, use angular typeahead

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Claies that it is never always a good idea to mix angular and jquery. But if you want to go with the same approach, then you can remove ng-model= 'newContact' in your html (as 2 way binding is not required with the following approach), and replace your complete function with below code.

```
$scope.complete = function(){
 var newContact = $('#tags').val();
 $scope.contacts.push(newContact);
 $('#tags').val();
}
```

Comment: Can u update in plunker and send me? @gopinath siva, its not working as exactly.

Comment: I have updated your code with the above code in jsfiddle over here(http://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/ue32gysc/)